# create a group of contacts NOT matching search criteria

Tags: civicrm-entity

I need to create a group of contacts who do NOT match a certain search criteria.  Is there some way to do so using the browser interface?

Thanks.
-- Hugh

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a group that DOES match the criteria.
2. Go to Search - Custom Search - Include/Exclude search.
3. Search for contacts excluding your group from (1).

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the [search builder](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/#search-builder)

Comment: For some search criteria that would work, but for example you could not find those who did not attend a specific event. It would only include those who did attended another event and not those who didn't attend any events. So Demerit's suggestion is more widely applicable and what I regularly use.

Comment: I agree for Event it's not adapted ;-)

Comment: agree Search Builder can be v helpful. i  think Tags and Groups is another area it won't help

Comment: Might be helpful for others if you could update your answer to provide a reference to Search Builder - https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/#search-builder

Comment: thanks Pete for the edit

Answer (score 1):

If you have an up-to-date version of CiviCRM you may want to check out [Search Kit](https://civicrm.org/searchkit) which is a new development that provides very powerful searching capabilities through the user interface.

There is some [limited documentation in the User Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/search-kit/) but note that this is still evolving.